# Geometric Distribution problem, how to solve when we have boundaries?

Tags: probability

> Find the probability that k is between $16$ and $19$, inclusive, for $p =   0.15$. Using Geometric Distribution.

Can you give a formula for calculation?

Comment: Just calculate $P(16\leq X\leq 19)=  P(X=16)+P(X=17)+P(X=18)+P(X=19)$

Comment: Note that it exists two definitions of the geometric distribution. It depends on the situation which of them should be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geometric distribution:
$P(X=x)=p(1−p)^x$, where $p=0.15$

You want:

$\begin{equation}
P(16\leq X \leq 19) = P(X=16)+P(X=17)+P(X=18)+P(X=19)\\
\end{equation}$